# Custom CSS text-align not working

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a very simple yet irritating issue. I have added a custom CSS code to my website which I am pasting below:

```
#site-logo {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
```

Everything seems to be fine but in WordPress, the *center* and *none* get highlighted as incorrect and the snippet doesn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the error or a link to the website?

Comment: please provide html code

Comment: Please post the html also.

Comment: @OfficialAntarctica Please don't request links to websites since they could be harmfull or inapropriate. I would recommend Screenshots or jsfiddle links with that show the error/problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin:0 auto;` instead

Example:

```
#site-logo {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explination what this does and how it fixes there problem? Explaining an answer helps the user a lot more then just posting code.

Comment: Hi. The same words are being highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Styling id's via # often causes issues as it's always more strict than using classes.

You could try:

1. Make sure that your CSS that's doing the overriding is loaded after the original styling.
2. Add important to your styles:

`#site-logo {
    text-align: center !important;
    float: none !important;
}`

Again I could not recommend using this unless you really have to, I would always use classes as they are easier to override.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The editor still highlights the same words.